How to set ENV VARs that can be used during PyCharm local development in AWS Glue Interactive Session Magics
I'm trying to make an ENV VAR available to use in an AWS Glue Interactive Session Magic. The ENV VAR would exist in a .env file. Essentially I want to do this:
%extra_py_files { SOME_PATH_TO_S3_DEPENDENCIES }
When the Interactive Session eventually kicks off it has no knowledge of the ENV VAR. I assume this is because the session is running as a Spark Cluster in AWS and its environment knows nothing about my local ENV VARs.
I have tried using the %env magic but it doesn't work. I have tried using PyCharms Jupyter Notebook server configuration to pass in the ENV VAR but it doesn't work. I have tried using os.getenv() BUT this messes up the magics and flow of the script. It is as if nothing can be executed before the magics .
Does anyone know how to make this work?
Thanks,
Sam
